# How to Apply css class on runTime

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to jQuery. I want to apply css class to my `<li>` element but it's not working. Can anyone help me?

My markup is:

```
<ul class='change'>
    <li>companyName</li>
    <ul id='uid'>
        <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany</li>
        <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany</li>
        <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany</li>
    </ul>

  <ul id='uid'>
        <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany2</li>
        <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany2</li>
        <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is when I call the `callTest()` method, I want to change the background color for that `<li>` i am trying this way not working:

```
$('#uid li').click(function () {
    console.log("call lil...'");
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
})
```

It's working fine but the first I selected **subcompany** it's applied `selected` class for that and now I selected **subcompany2** for this also applied `selected` class but on this time I want to **remove subcompany** class. How can I do this?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ggNrr/ are you getting any errors?

Comment: You don't need the `onclick="callTest()"` if you are using jQuery click handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your HTML this way:

```
<ul class='change'>
    <li>companyName</li>
    <ul id='uid'>
        <li>subcompany</li>
        <li>subcompany</li>
        <li>subcompany</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

and ADD this JS this way:

```
$('#uid > li').each(function () {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        console.log("call lil...'");
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like you are targeting all `li` elements, including the parent instead of targeting only those are under `uid`

```
$('#uid li').click(function () {
    console.log("call lil...'");
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X7GKD/)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine actually

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    console.log("call lil...'");
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Here is the demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufYfX/)

Check your html file. There must be a problem including your script or the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You code is right. Since you've added this script in head/body it is reason for not working.

So just **Wrap it in `$(document).ready(function()..`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul li').click(function(){
    console.log("call lil...'");
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    })
});
```

Also try to used **`.on()`** event handler like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
    console.log("call lil...'");
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` at the `li` and add handlers when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li').click(function () {
    console.log("call lil...'");
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    callTest();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cGDjy/)

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(e.target).addClass('selected');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a HTML-issues here:

```
<ul class='change'>
    <li>companyName
        <ul id='uid'>
            <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany</li>
            <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany</li>
            <li onClick='callTest()'>subcompany</li>
        </ul>
    </li> <!-- I moved this one -->
</ul>
```

regarding your jQuery you can do it like this instead:

```
$('ul.change > li').click(function(){ //Only applies to the direct child of ul.change
    console.log("call lil...'");
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Call callTest() inside che click handler.

Answer (score 0):

onclick attribute is not needed in the li elements. Remove those